# Run time difference between a 4-cell (43 Wh) battery and an 8-cell (58 Wh) battery?

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life, laptop-repair, dell-xps

Is there a significant improvement in battery run time going from a 4-cell (43 Wh) battery to an 8-cell (58 Wh) battery? How much longer will it run (percentage-wise)?

Comment: What do you mean what are the differences. The only difference I see is that the 4 cell battery is more effective?

Comment: So I should choose 4 cells battery with 43 Watt an hour right in order to get longer battery.

Comment: I didn't say that.  I just said it was more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important metric is the Wh. If you go from 40Wh to 80Wh you will roughly last twice as long on battery. How long it will last in your case depends on how much power your laptop will consume. If it lasts two hours on the 43Wh battery it should last about thirty five minutes extra on the 58Wh.